# How to compare a field to a field of a array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a documents like below. I want to retrieve all documents whose address.city == "newyork" and address.id == active.

```
    [  
     {
    "name": "star1",
    "active": 1,
    "address": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "city": "newyork"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "city": "sydney"
      }
    ]  
   },  
  {
    "name": "star2",
    "active": 2,
    "address": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "city": "newyork"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "city": "london"
      }
    ]  
}
]
```

I have written below query and it Partially works, But It is not returning complete document. I can't use unwind. Do we have any solution without using "unwind". Is it possible to solve a problem only with $match

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$address"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          "$active",
          "$address.id"
        ]
      },
      "address.city": "newyork"
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: "... retrieve all documents ..." After the `"$unwind"`, you are not really returning the original document.  What exactly do you want to return?

Comment: You can use this query: `collection.find( { "address.city": "newyork" } )`. The same filter can be used in the `$match` aggregation stage (no need to unwind).

Comment: I need complete document. my query returns partial document. Corrected the text.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
"$addFields": {
  "address": {
    "$filter": {
      "input": "$address",
      "as": "a",
      "cond": {
        $and: [
          {
            $eq: [
              "$$a.id",
              "$active"
            ]
          },
          {
            $eq: [
              "$$a.city",
              "newyork"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
},
{
 $match: {
  address: {
     $ne: []
    }
  }
}
])
```

Explained:

1. Use addFields/filter to match only matching documents in the array.
2. Remove the documents with empty address from the array for the cases where no subdocuments is found.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HHqwQPqKvyM)

Comment: I need complete document with all address field. this query returns only one address. i missed this part in earlier question. now i added it.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to match the whole document containing at least one entry having {address.id==active and address.city==newyork } here is an option:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
 {
   $match: {
    $expr: {
      "$in": [
        {
          id: "$active",
          city: "newyork"
        },
        "$address"
       ]
     }
   }
 }
])
```

Explained:

Match only documents having at least one object in address array with id==$active and city=="newyork"

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/C2W4t0glC3h)

In case we expect different order inside the address objects , the more correct option is as follow:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
 $match: {
  $expr: {
    $or: [
      {
        "$in": [
          {
            id: "$active",
            city: "newyork"
          },
          "$address"
        ]
      },
      {
        "$in": [
          {
            city: "newyork",
            id: "$active"
          },
          "$address"
        ]
      }
    ]
   }
  }
 }
])
```

Explained:

Match only documents having at least one object in array with { id==$active and city=="newyork" } or { city=="newyork" and id==$active }

[Playground 2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7izfo8W6j1H)